# Using a MIDI pedalboard

Tags: midi

My wife is a pianist and organist. I am in IT so I do the technology stuff :)

She would like to set up a rig for organ practice. And I can see MIDI pedalboards available. But how do I make this pedalboard work with a keyboard to make an organ practice rig? I sadly never used MIDI before, except for an experiment where I ran software synthesis from a keyboard via a MIDI cable.

Is it possible to avoid using a PC? I'm just afraid of the pedalboard and keyboard going out of sync, and of the latency in general, if I use software synthesis.

She has a Clavinova 220 which has a MIDI IN connection. Would this mean that the Clavinova can handle the pedalboard, adding it to its keyboard in its organ voice? (That voice is rather limited but for practice this might not really matter).

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, I think, but I used an old pedalboard from an old electronic organ, used (I think) an *Arduino* pcb to connect all the 12 pedals to a midi out. That then gets connected, in my case, to a Nanobass which gives me 256 bass sounds. It could be connected to any midi in and switched to any sound available. The pedalboard was a heck of a lot cheaper than a ready made one, but I had to build a framework for the pedals from wood. They could have been housed in a flightcase, or travelcase. 25 key pedals are also available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect the pedalboard's MIDI output directly to the CLP's MIDI input.

See p. 29 of the manual; you should set

- the receive channel to <strike>the correct number</strike> "ALL" (so that the Clavinova plays the notes received from its input), and
- "Local Control" to "ON" (so that the Clavinova plays notes from its own keys).